Prevent PowerShell Replace from adding a new line in within the replacement string
I have a text file which has 23718 lines of text and is UTF-16 LE with BOM (Unicode) encoded. I am using a PowerShell CLI in my batch file to find and replace certain text.
This is the code I am using:
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Write-Host modifying InventoryItemTypes.GER...;" ^
    "$file = '%target%\InventoryItemTypes.GER';" ^
    "$content = (Get-Content -Raw -Encoding UTF8 $file);" ^
    "$content -Replace '(?m)(Weapon_AssaultRifle_.*_DisplayName)=\b(?!<color:.*>.*<\/color>\b)(.+)$', '$1=<color:R=1 G=1 B=0>$2</color>' |" ^
    "Set-Content -Encoding Unicode -NoNewLine $file"

My issue is that the command replaces the strings but puts </color> on a new line for each replacement. The result looks like this for each replaced line:
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_ATAC_DisplayName=<color:R=1 G=1 B=0>ATAC 424
</color>

I have no idea why this is happening. Using my regex definition on regex101 it should replace the text without putting </color> on a new line.
This is a snippet of the text I want to replace:
...
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_STAR_Slot3_Valentines_Leased_CreatorName=Amorous Marketplace
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_STAR_Slot3_Valentines_Leased_DisplayName=<color:R=1 G=0.45 B=1>STAR 556 'Love-Gun'</color>
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_Star-LCR_PR1_Joker_CreatorName=Joker Distribution
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_Star-LCR_PR1_Joker_DisplayName=STAR 556 'LCR' PR1
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Base_CreatorName=Agrotech
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Base_DisplayName=VAS-R2_Base
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Base_Joker_CreatorName=Agrotech
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Base_Joker_DisplayName=VAS-R2 'Sword'
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Base_Slot3_Armas_CreatorName=Agrotech
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Base_Slot3_Armas_DisplayName=VAS-R2 'Sword' NFCP 3
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Base_Slot3_Joker_CreatorName=Agrotech
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Base_Slot3_Joker_DisplayName=VAS-R2 'Sword' JT3
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Sights_CreatorName=Agrotech
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Sights_DisplayName=VAS-R2_Sights
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Sights_Slot3_Armas_CreatorName=Agrotech
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Sights_Slot3_Armas_DisplayName=VAS-R2 'Scepter' NFCP 3
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Silenced_CreatorName=Agrotech
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Silenced_DisplayName=VAS-R2_Silenced
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Silenced_Slot3_Armas_CreatorName=Agrotech
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VAS-R2-Silenced_Slot3_Armas_DisplayName=VAS-R2 'Crown' NFCP 3
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_Vespa_CreatorName=
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_Vespa_DisplayName=Vespa
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VespaStock_CreatorName=
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VespaStock_DisplayName=Vespa Stock
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VespaTactical_CreatorName=
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_VespaTactical_DisplayName=Vespa Tactical
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_MattTest_CreatorName=
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_MattTest_DisplayName=
...

I want to add <color:R=1 G=1 B=0> and </color> to all lines that include Weapon_AssaultRifle_.*_Displayname= and don't already have a color code specified like in the 2nd line of the snippet.
Example:
Change
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_Star-LCR_PR1_Joker_DisplayName=STAR 556 'LCR' PR1

to
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_Star-LCR_PR1_Joker_DisplayName=<color:R=1 B=1 B=0>STAR 556 'LCR' PR1</color>

and keep
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_AssaultRifle_STAR_Slot3_Valentines_Leased_DisplayName=<color:R=1 G=0.45 B=1>STAR 556 'Love-Gun'</color>

and
InventoryItemTypes_Weapon_MattTest_DisplayName=

as it is.

Can you check : "$content -Replace '(?m)(Weapon_AssaultRifle_.*_DisplayName)=\b(?!<color:.*>.*<\/color>\b)([^\r\n]+)$', '$1=<color:R=1 G=1 B=0>$2</color>' |" ^ instead?

The problem might be here: (.+)$ and changing it to ([^\r\n]+)$ might work. Can you add real inputs and actual outputs to your question because there are other issues with your regex?

@123 Using ([^\r\n]+)$ instead of (.+)$ worked! Thank you very much! I don't understand why my regex definition didn't work though. On regex101 it was working perfectly fine. If I understood your question right, I have added a snippet of the text and the find and replace strings as well as what has to be excluded.

I added a few more patterns that you can look into.

The use of multiline flag (?m) with (.+)$ is a problem:

You can change (.+)$ to ([^\r\n]+)$.

Or alternatively, it seems that these regular expressions:


(Weapon_AssaultRifle_[^\r\n]*_DisplayName)=(\w[^\r\n]*)$
(Weapon_AssaultRifle_[^\r\n]*_DisplayName)=([^<\r\n]*)$
(Weapon_AssaultRifle_[^\r\n]*_DisplayName)=([^<][^\r\n]*)$

being replaced by:
$1=<color:R=1 G=1 B=0>$2</color>

might actually work.
